# Merge PowerPoint Files in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powerpoint

i want to merge 2 PowerPoint Files/Slides which are hosted within a SharePoint Env. It has to be done on the Server Side. I also found some Solutions, but all of them need Namespaces which arnt available for me:

DocumentFormat.OpenXML // Has to be installed on the Server to be accessable. Impossible :S
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint // Even Office PP has to be installed on the Server, a absolute nogo.

Does someone know another NameSpace which gives me the required functionality to merge two PowerPoint Slides? For example, in SharePoint you are able to "View" PPT files within the Browser, there is even a sp-service for this, but i did not find any information how to contact it and maybe do the merge over it.

Thanks for any Help in advance :)

Best Regards
THO

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is with the requirement to do this "server side". SharePoint is merely the storage, you should be able to use a server that allows you to install the required Office document manipulation tools and simply read the documents from the SharePoint server and web services.

Even "server side" your code is going to consist of the following steps:

1. Download ppt files
2. Merge ppt files
3. Upload merged file to SharePoint